# String literal inside backticks in bash

Tags: bash, disown

I would like to create a process that runs in the background and waits for 2 seconds and prints a literal. I'm trying to do

```
`sleep 2 && echo "hello"` &
```

However, it's trying to execute `hello`:

```
Command 'hello' not found
...
```

How can I make this work and just print `hello`?

Comment: `(sleep 2 && echo "hello") &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backticks expand to the string the enclosed command outputs. If you don't care about the output, don't use backticks.

```
string=`sleep 2 && echo "hello"`
echo "$string"  # hello
```

This prints `hello` after two seconds, but doesn't block:

```
(sleep 2 && echo hello) &
{ sleep 2 && echo hello ; } &
```